# Trying to switch out of my app and into settings, but it seems to boomerang back...sort of

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, openurl, fast-app-switching

So I'm using the following line of code to switch to Settings when I have a `CKErrorCode.NotAuthenticated` issue:

```
let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
let result = UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

I'll show the code in context momentarily. **It seems to go fine at first (my app goes to the background), but then I'm brought back to a new version of my app. The back button unwinds to Settings (it is labeled accordingly), and from there I can unwind back to the original app.** Aside from the fact that the iteration of my app that gets opened from Settings fails to load anything (it is titled, but otherwise is a blank white screen), everything else is working normally.

This is the first time I've created a XIB so that may be something to keep in mind. I'm doing error handling in a switch statement triggered at the following case:

```
        case CKErrorCode.NotAuthenticated.rawValue:

        //Should check account status here...

        // If account not logged in...
        let message = "Your device needs to be logged in to your iCloud Account in order for Voyager to work correctly. After clicking 'OK' you can login at Settings/iCloud..."
        presentAlertMessageToUser(message) { action in
            if let goToSettingsURL = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
print("E3")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    let result = UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(goToSettingsURL)
print("E4: \(result)")
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see I'm presenting the `UIAlertViewController` in a method titled `presentAlertMessageToUser(message: String?, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?)`. It doesn't seem to be having any problems itself but you can see it here:

```
    private func presentAlertMessageToUser(message: String?, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?) {
print("G0")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Connection Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    if let completionBlock = handler {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: completionBlock))
    } else {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
print("G2")
        unowned let me = self
        me.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
print("G1")
}
```

For this error case in the switch statement, I disabled the retry attempt and I also verified that it wasn't executing any parts of the sequence multiple times. If any other part of the code would be helpful I can post it here along with the output to my console where I'm using those print lines to monitor app's progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this was apparently a dumb question. I expected to get dropped off at settings, not my own app's settings (which is empty and appears blank).